# Use color with alpha fill NSView?

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsview

I write a window and two views, 
set background color of window to blue, 
and draw a image in view1, 
and fill view2 with a color with alpha,like this:

//AppDelegate

```
[self.window setLevel:(NSStatusWindowLevel + 2)];
TestView *view1 = [[TestView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, self.window.frame.size.width, self.window.frame.size.height)];

TestView2 *view2 = [[TestView2 alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, self.window.frame.size.width, self.window.frame.size.height)];


[self.window setContentView:view1];
[self.window.contentView addSubview:view2];
```

//View1

```
   - (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];

    // Drawing code here.
    NSImage *image = [NSImage imageNamed:@"testImage"];
    [image drawInRect:dirtyRect];
    }
```

//view2

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];

    // Drawing code here.
    [[[NSColor redColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5] set];
    NSRectFill(dirtyRect);
    }
```

But when the app run, I found I the backgroundcolor of window and image of View1 did not show, only the view2 show, and it is transparent,through it can see the desktop.

If I did not add subview view2, the app runs correctly, the blue background color and the image.

Does anybody know why, really thanks for the help, I will wait on line.

Answer (score 2):

I change the NSRectFill to

```
NSRectFillUsingOperation(dirtyRect, NSCompositeSourceOver);
```

Then it turns right.